# How to not infringe copyrights from Nintendo?

Tags: copyright, trademark

I am thinking about developing a free Pokedex App with pokémon information (pokémon data and images) for Android, but I do not want to infringe any copyright or use trademarks because I want no trouble.

Using pokémon sprites and data from a free wiki, for example [bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number) would be OK? If not, what advices could you guys give for me to avoid infringing any copyright or trademarks from Nintendo?

Answer (score 3):

### You can’t use pictures

You can’t use any of [these](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex), nor can you make your own art that is derived from these. That’s copyright infringement and there is no fair use defence because you are specifically trying to do something Nintendo already does.

You can reproduce that stats of the Pokémon because stats are facts (even if they are facts about fictional things) and facts are not protected by copyright.

Comment: Does that mean that Bulbapedia is infringing copyright because it uses copyrighted images?

Comment: @THummus It probably does. But the company may have made a strategic decision for non-legal reasons to not fully enforce its rights.

Comment: @ohwilleke or it may have a licence we don’t know about

Comment: @DaleM Possible, but unlikely

Comment: @THummus Each image on that site seems to have an information page saying that the file is copyrighted and comes from the Pokedex itself, and that the contributors believe the image to be "fair use". Of course, saying "this is fair use" does not automatically make it so.